# Resizing bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am working on an android project. When i am trying to resizing a bitmap the app unfortunately stopped and in Logcat giving a message "only the mutable bitmap can resize". I tried to convert my bitmap into a mutable bit still the same problem.What may be the solution.
my code :

```
public DrawingTheBall(Context context) {
    super(context);

    ball= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.start_bg);;

}

@Override
protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

     ball.setWidth(canvas.getWidth());
     ball.setHeight(canvas.getHeight());


    Paint p=new Paint();
    canvas.drawBitmap(ball,0,0,p);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bitmap.setWidth` and `Bitmap.setHeight` are introduced from API19 (KitKat).

Didn't you set the `minSdkVersion` to 19 or later?

update:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inMutable = true;
ball= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.start_bg, options);
```

Comment: @user3768819 ok, then did you give 'BitmapFactory.Options().inMutable = true' as the 'BitmapFactory.decodeResource' method third argument?

Answer (score 2):

Since you only scale the original bitmap you might want to use the folllowing method

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)
```

Complete code:

```
Bitmap newBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ball, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), true);
canvas.drawBitmap(newBmp, 0, 0, p);
```

Consider moving the "newBmp" line to another method such as `onSizeChanged(...)`. `onDraw(...)` will get called pretty much all the time and it would be slow and wasteful to recreate the same bitmap all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a scaled down version of your bitmap resource into memory pass properly set `BitmapFactory.Options` to `decodeResource` method. [Load a Scaled Down Version into Memory](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) If you want to scale bitmap which you already have in memory use `Bitmap#createScaledBitmap`.